# How to get headphones moved around event using react native?

Tags: reactjs, events, react-native, event-handling, jsx

I am writing an audio application and I need to pause playing music when I pull out the headphones. I use react-native-sound.
Can I listen to headphones, moved events? How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [react-native-music-control](https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control). As far as I read in their docs, they say it plays well with react-native-sound.

See the [register to events](https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control#register-to-events) section in their docs.

> On iOS this event will also be triggered by the audio router change event.
>
> This happens when headphones are unplugged or a bluetooth audio peripheral disconnects from the device:
>
> ```
> MusicControl.on('pause', ()=> {
>   // Do your magic here. 
> });
> ```

That's how you can do it on iOS! Unfortunately, I can't find any info if on Android the behavior is the same or if not - what's the workaround there.